# Let $W = \operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{w}_1\}$, where...

Tags: linear-algebra

Just checking to make sure this is right!!!
Let $W = \operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{w}_1\}$, where
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{w}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
1. Find a basis for $W$.
A basis for $W$ is
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}.
\end{equation*}
2. Find a basis for $W^{\perp}$.
Finding a basis for $W^{\perp}$ is the same as finding the basis for $\text{null}(A^T)$ where $A^T = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$. Hence, a basis for $W^{\perp}$ is
\begin{equation*}
\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}.
\end{equation*}
3. Check that $\text{dim}(W)+\text{dim}(W^{\perp}) = \text{dim}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.
Well that is obvious!

Comment: At the end, what is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that looks correct. Another way you could have done it is that you know as a theorem that $\dim(W)+\dim(W^\perp)=\dim(\mathbb R^3)$, and so you know there must be two vectors in the basis of $W^\perp$, which you can find by finding any two linearly independent vectors that dot with $\mathbf{w}_1$ to be $0$, which you have done. This process just makes it more obvious that you have in fact found a basis, and that there is no "mysterious unaccounted vector" that is actually part of $W^\perp$.

Comment: Great thank you!